# Why is audio streaming harder than video streaming?

Tags: linux, audio, video, streaming, pulse-audio

I have two separate Linux computers on the same LAN. One computer has speakers, the other computer has a monitor. To play a movie with video and sound I have two options:

1. Play the movie on the computer with the speakers, and transfer the video over the network to the computer with the monitor.
2. Play the movie on the computer with the monitor, and transfer the audio over the network to the computer with the speakers.

The first options works well using X11 forwarding:

```
$ ssh -X computer1
$ mpv movie.avi
```

For the second option I tried [PulseAudio's network setup](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/), setting the following in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` on both computers:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
load-module module-zeroconf-discover
```

Then, I run `mpv` on the computer with the monitor. This works, but the audio is so choppy that it makes the movie unwatchable. Why is it that streaming video poses no problem but streaming audio is apparently hard? Doesn't uncompressed video use much more bandwidth than uncompressed audio?

Comment: Is the available bandwidth symmetric in both directions?

Comment: Good question! I investigated and found that `scp` reports about 10MB/s in both directions. That isn't much, which could explain the choppy audio. However, I can't explain why the video still looks decent!

Comment: When the video stream malfunctions, you can still see the last picture. When the audio stream malfunctions, you can keep the last sound alive. Well you can, but playing the same buffer over and over is not very pleasant!

Comment: @DanielB this is the real answer to my question. Both audio and video were sub-par with only 10MB/s, it's just that I noticed the audio chopping way before I noticed the video skipping frames.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that bandwidth isn't the problem.  What you're encountering is jitter and underruns.  The classic fix for that is to increase latency (so the hose doesn't run dry, so to speak).
For PulseAudio itself, in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`, increase `default-fragment-size-msec` and maybe also `default-fragments`.
Also see the Scheduling section in https://linux.die.net/man/5/pulse-daemon.conf, and a [discussion](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=44862&start=0) thereof.
There may be further parameters to tweak for the TCP connection, but I'm unfamiliar with that end of things.

Comment: The problem can also be solved by increasing the bandwidth, so in a sense, bandwidth _is_ the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For my own and anyone else's future reference, here's the setup I used to successfully stream audio without buffer underruns. It works flawlessly provided both systems have a decent network connection. (For me it was choppy on 2.4 GHz WiFi, but fine on 5 GHz WiFi.)

Let's call the system with the speakers `speakers` and the system with the screen `screen`.

- On both systems, install the Zeroconf module:

  ```
  $ sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
  ```
- On `speakers`, add the following to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

  ```
  load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
  load-module module-zeroconf-publish
  ```
- On `screen`, add the following to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

  ```
  load-module module-zeroconf-discover
  ```
- Copy the file `~/.config/pulse/cookie` from `screen` to `speakers` (or the other way around, presumably).
- On `screen` run `pavucontrol` to set the output device. As you can see in the screenshot below, the following "Virtual Output Devices" were automatically added (which also reveals that my `speakers` system is actually called `sea`).

[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: Your own explicit questions are "Why is it that streaming video poses no problem but streaming audio is apparently hard? Doesn't uncompressed video use much more bandwidth than uncompressed audio?". This answer does not answer these *at all*. You did not ask "how can I fix?", but judging by your answer this is what you wanted to ask. Please make the answer match the question or the other way around. In general this would be easy if your answer was the only one, not necessarily easy otherwise. Fortunately the other answer also tries to answer "how can I fix?", so *this* should be the question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you are completely right that my original question has not been answered. I posted my own answer to document what I have done to solve my problem, but the cause of the problem is still unknown. If you are anyone else would be willing to answer the original question I will mark it, rightfully, as the accepted answer.